# Minkowski sum (Polyhedra)

Tags: geometry

I'd like to understand and visualize the minkowski sum using GeoGebra.

I already managed to create the sum of a triangle and a square - very simple for beginners like me!

Now I wonder how I can visualize the sum of a cube and a ball!
It doesn't have to be GeoGebra - if I'll be able to draw it by hand I'll be satisfied. However, I can imagine that drawing it by hand would be extremely difficult?

And, above all, what does $cube + ball$ look like?

Answer (score 2):

It's a cube with rounded edges and corners.

[image]